# Trouble with Java DecimalFormat

Tags: java, formatting, decimal, decimalformat

How would I create a DecimalFormat that would only have seven digits total and also have it favor the left hand side of the number.

For example: 1234.5678 would transform to 1234.567
             1.2345678 would transform to 1.234567
             1234567.8 would transform to 1234567

Comment: May be NumberFormat is what you are looking for? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: And what do you want to happen when fewer than seven digits are available?  i.e., if you pass in 1234, should it format to 1234 or 1234.000?  And what should happen to 12345678? (would it become 12345670? 12345678? 12345680? 1.23456e7? 1.234567e7?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DecimalFormat can't do what you want, but I think this is more a String question. Once you have your formatted decimal, you can do this:

```
String number = "123.45678"; // output from decimal format

number = number.substring(0, 7 + (number.contains(".") ? 1 : 0)).replaceAll("\\.$", "");
```

This truncates the string length to 7, or 8 if a decimal point is found (then removing any trailing decimal points), which is what you require.

Here's some test code:

```
private static String format(String number) {
    return number.substring(0, 7 + (number.contains(".") ? 1 : 0)).replaceAll("\\.$", "");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(format("1234567"));
    System.out.println(format("1.2345678"));
    System.out.println(format("1234.5678"));
    System.out.println(format("1234567.8"));
    System.out.println(format(".12345678"));
}
```

Output:

```
1234567
1.234567
1234.567
1234567
```

.1234567

Comment: +1. You're right, string manipulation is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: But how does the OP get a formatted decimal in the first place?

Comment: `double x = /* some decimal number */; String number = "" + x;` Now the OP has a decimal to pass into the above funciton.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you do this kind of formatting with DecimalFormat, but you perform String manipulation

```
double d = 1234567.8;
System.out.println(new StringBuilder()
     .append(d).substring(0, 8)
     .replaceAll("\\.$", "") // to remove last decimal
     .toString());
```

Comment: Not quite: When `d = .12345678d` you get `"0.123456"`